# Is every Super Mario Run level iteration identical?

Tags: super-mario-run

I am strictly talking single player or World mode, where you go through levels.

I know that the levels slightly change to adapt to what *special coin* you're on (pink, purple, or black) but I am asking about every *run*.

Will every iteration of a level be identical (or will there be random adaptations to the level regardless of the special coin you're on)?

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed hard to find a source for this, but in general, I'd back up Reinhard's answer. Most levels in World Tour mode don't contain any random components as far as I can tell after playing the game quite a lot for the last week (collecting all coloured coins in the game).

However, I *can* report on one level that definitely has a random component: the first Boo House level, 2-1, has small rooms with multiple green doors in each of them. One of them is the real door that leads to the next room and the other doors are fake and lead you back to the bottom of the current room. Which of the doors is the right one appears to be chosen randomly — it definitely changes between runs (and the fake doors can be recognised by their periodic shaking).

I also believe that Bowser's movement patterns are random. This is the definitely the case for the final level (which I've grinded enough for black coins to be sure). I haven't played the earlier castles often enough but it *seems* that his choice of jump, fireball and direction of fireball is somewhat random. For other enemies like Lakitu and Bats which don't always move the same I can't say whether they are random or whether they are just very sensitive to the player's position.

Answer (score -3):

Yes I believe so, they are all well designed stages.

Toad rally is kinda random by the way

Comment: A source to back this up would be very useful, especially since this question has a bounty on it, indicating that the asker seeks a well-thought-out answer.

Comment: 4 votes down? Are you kidding me?. You can't find a proof on the Internet because it's so obvious that everyone who plays this game will get a feeling of it. And that's how the game is designed, as well as the original Super Mario Bros. is designed.

Comment: @Reinhard This just isn't a good answer format.  The "I believe so" in itself is somewhat questionable.  "they are all well designed stages." is an opinion that has nothing to do with the question.  "Toad rally is kinda random by the way" is extremely vague.  Why is Toad rally "kinda random"?  It's just not a very high quality answer, that is why there are votes down (I know this is way after the comment).